# Counting list items in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating a statistical analysis workbook, and I have a question.

If I create a list on one of the worksheets, and make a data validation for only the values in that list in more than one worksheet, is there any function that would allow me to get the number of times an element of that list was used in the several worksheets?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2541-excel-countif-across-multiple-worksheets.html

The most straightforward way is to add a series of COUNTIF statements together depending on the number of sheets you have.

For example:

```
=COUNTIF('SheetA'!A:L, A1) + COUNTIF('SheetB'!A:L, A1) + COUNTIF('SheetC'!A:L, A1)
```

Comment: Not really what I had in mind. Because i have several list that have the same value.

If tou create a list and the list is used in several sheets, how could you count the number of times that a element of that list is used?

Comment: @AndréCastelo I'm not sure I understand. Do you have some sample data you can provide as an example?